# SQLite SELECT statement fails in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been working to create a basic application that queries a database of records that I own to suggest what I should listen to next. My current draft requests that the user enter the current album that they are listening to and then queries the database to return the related genre, and other artists in that genre.

The `c.execute` and `c.fetchone()` commands that I use to return the artist and genre work twice. The code fails when I attempt to set `reclist = c.fetchall()`.

The worst part of this entire thing is that I had the code working for a few minutes before going back and tinkering with a few things. I guess I've learned my lesson about making 'innocuous' changes.

Schema for the database:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE album (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
album TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE genre (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
genre TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE artist (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
artist TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE aag (
artist_id INTEGER,
album_id INTEGER,
genre_id INTEGER
);
```

Full Python code below:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

conn = sqlite3.connect('aag_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

print "Are you listening to a record right now?"
uresponse1 = raw_input("[y / N]")

#collect query information from user
if uresponse1 == "N":
    sys.exit()

print "What is the name of the record are you listening to?"
uresponse2 = raw_input("> ")

print "Let me see what I know about %r" % (uresponse2)

#query record database
c.execute('''Select artist.artist FROM 
    artist, album, aag WHERE 
    artist.id=aag.artist_id AND
    album.id=aag.album_id AND
    album.album=?''', (uresponse2,))
artist_return = str(c.fetchone())

if artist_return == "None":
    print "I guess I don't know anything about that record."
    sys.exit()

#confirm match
print "Oh do you mean %r by %r" % (uresponse2, artist_return)

uresponse3 = raw_input("[y / N]")

if uresponse3 == "N":
    sys.exit()

#query record database for genre of user input
c.execute('''Select genre.genre FROM 
    genre, album, aag WHERE 
    genre.id=aag.genre_id AND 
    album.id=aag.album_id AND 
    album=?''', (uresponse2,))
genre_return = str(c.fetchone())

if genre_return == "None":
    print "I guess I don't know anything about that genre."
    sys.exit()

#confirm match
print "I would classify that album as %r music" % (genre_return)

print "If you like that you may also enjoy these records:"

#query record database on genre
c.execute('''Select artist, album FROM 
    genre, album, artist, aag WHERE 
    genre.id=aag.genre_id AND 
    album.id=aag.album_id AND 
    artist.id=aag.artist_id AND
    genre.genre=?''', (genre_return,))
reclist = c.fetchall()

print reclist
```

Comment: And the lesson to use revision control such as `git`!

Comment: What was the error message / stacktrace returned?

Comment: There was no error message which is part of what is so frustrating. When I print reclist I end up with a value of None. The test that I've been using though has several other artists in the same genre. To make it even MORE frustrating the final query works when I execute it in sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed my code several times and tried setting the variable `genre_return = c.fetchone()[0]`. This seems to pass the actual table value back through sqlite rather than the tuple that was being passed before.

I have tested this method with by setting `genre_return` to selections based on `genre.genre` as illustrated above as well as `genre.id`. Queries worked successfully in both cases.

I can't explain *why* the `album_return = str(c.fetchone())` code can successfully query the database (as a tuple) where my `genre_return` couldn't but my problem seems to have been solved.

This has been quite the learning experience. Hopefully this can help someone else trying to work with sqlite in python.

Comment: fetch one return the first element of a collection as a tuple, so [0] get the first élément of tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!